# Grouping of column

Tags: sql, select

```
Group   Error  
1           a  
1           b  
1           c    
2           a  
2           b  
3           a
```

I want write an SQL query to get that record only which has either **only** a or b as an error or both a and b
Output should be Group 2, 3  as
Group 2 contains both a and b , Group 3 contains only a.
Any Group  that contains Error apart from a,b should not be returned.

Answer (score 2):

I'd group and use a condition on a count of errors that aren't `a` or `b`:

```
SELECT   [group] -- Assuming MS SQL Syntax, like Ross Presser did in his answer
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY [group]
HAVING   COUNT(CASE WHEN [error] NOT IN ('a', 'b') THEN 1 END) = 0
```

Comment: should be `[error] NOT IN` ... you wrote `[group] NOT IN`

Comment: @RossPresser oops, momentary lapse of concentration. Thanks for noticing - edited and fixed.

Comment: no problem. I got the whole question wrong (OP wants either a or b or both; I thought it was just both) and gave an answer that didn't even do what I said it did. Thankfully there's a delete button ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Unsure of the DBMS and so the following may not be applicable, but to offer another option using a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.Group
FROM Table1 a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table1 b WHERE a.Group = b.Group AND b.Error NOT IN ('a','b'))
```

---

Or using a `LEFT JOIN` on a query of Groups containing at least one Error code not equal to `a` or `b`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.Group
FROM 
    Table1 a LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT t.Group
        FROM Table1 t
        WHERE t.Error <> 'a' AND t.Error <> 'b'
    ) b
    ON a.Group = b.Group
WHERE b.Group IS NULL
```

---

And one more *very specific* to your example, but just for fun -

```
SELECT t.Group
FROM Table1 t
GROUP BY t.Group
HAVING MIN(t.Error) >= 'a' AND MAX(t.Error) <= 'b'
```

---

Replace `Table1` with the name of your table in all of the above.

Comment: Mmmm... correlated queries.  <gaaarlll drool>